# String aggregation in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have small sample dataset as follows;

```
          BODY
        ---------------------
      1.    #GPREV - CSR - description - formatting - container info //
           #CREV - body - missing - total kgs //
      2.   #CREV -  body- inaccurate - weights//
          #CREV - body - missing - description//
          #FPREV - body - inaccurate - hs code format//
```

The goal is to do string aggregation using the tags `CREV, FPREV, and GPREV`  as the grouping column, and get following output;

```
       GPREV_REASON                |   FPREV_REASON              |  CREV_REASON
#GPREV - CSR - description.          #FPREV - body - inaccurate.   #CREV -  body- inaccurate - weights//
- formatting - container info //.     - hs code format//             #CREV - body - missing - description
                                                                    #CREV - body - missing - total kgs
```

As you can see, we are concatenating messages with appropriate tags, namely CREV, FPREV, and GPREV. Can I kindly get some help to do this in snowflake?

Comment: can you form valid tables so it is clear what "was where" so it more clear what "will go where" in the answer..

Answer (score 0):

It's rather unclear how your source data looks, and how you are trying to project it.

One perspective is it's a list of values, and you want three lists:

```
SELECT 
    listagg(iff(startswith(column1,'#GPREV'), column1, null), ' !! ') as gprev,
    listagg(iff(startswith(column1,'#FPREV'), column1, null), ' !! ') as fprev,
    listagg(iff(startswith(column1,'#CREV'), column1, null), ' !! ') as cprev
FROM VALUES 
    ('#GPREV - CSR - description - formatting - container info //'),
    ('#CREV - body - missing - total kgs //'),
    ('#CREV -  body- inaccurate - weights//'),
    ('#CREV - body - missing - description//'),
    ('#FPREV - body - inaccurate - hs code format//');
```

| GPREV | FPREV | CPREV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #GPREV - CSR - description - formatting - container info // | #FPREV - body - inaccurate - hs code format// | #CREV - body - missing - total kgs // !! #CREV - body- inaccurate - weights// !! #CREV - body - missing - description// |

Another is that you have blocks of stuff that need splitting and reforming as sort three blocks:

```
SELECT
    listagg(iff(startswith(str,'#GPREV'), str, null), ' !! ') as gprev,
    listagg(iff(startswith(str,'#FPREV'), str, null), ' !! ') as fprev,
    listagg(iff(startswith(str,'#CREV'), str, null), ' !! ') as cprev
FROM (
    
SELECT  
    trim(trim(s.value,'\r')) as str
FROM VALUES 
    ('#GPREV - CSR - description - formatting - container info //
      #CREV - body - missing - total kgs //'),
    ('#CREV -  body- inaccurate - weights//
     #CREV - body - missing - description//
     #FPREV - body - inaccurate - hs code format//') as v
    ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(v.column1, '\n') as s
)
```

gives:

| GPREV | FPREV | CPREV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| #GPREV - CSR - description - formatting - container info // | #FPREV - body - inaccurate - hs code format// | #CREV - body - missing - total kgs // !! #CREV - body- inaccurate - weights// !! #CREV - body - missing - description// |

Where you might want to replace `!!` with something that has more meaning to you.